# How do I write to database with PHP based on result of a JavaScript function? (FB app)

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

There are two of us working on a [Facebook competition application](https://www.facebook.com/MyPuzzler/app_142974305841145).  My boss has got the button states working for when a user likes, enters email details, and shares the pages.  The problem arises when a user clicks 'share' and then clicks cancel when the 'post to profile' box comes up.  The app still uses the 'done' button state regardless of whether a user actually posts to their profile or not.

The JavaScript is a function that calls Facebook API to post to the users’ timeline:

```
// calling the API ...  
function postToFeed() {
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://www.domain.co.uk',
        picture: 'https://www.domain.co.uk/FacebookTabs/pics/fblogo.png',
        name: 'My company',
        caption: 'This is a test',
        description: 'Using My company to do your best'
    };
FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            return('Post was published.');
        } else {
            return('Post was not published.');
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, I want to use the result in a PHP if/else statement to write to a database if the Facebook share is successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: @alfasin Thanks, is this for general reference or is it directly aimed at something I have/have not done in the past?

Comment: The question had been open less than an hour and there was only one answer at the time you are saying I should have accepted a best answer, and that was just 'use AJAX'.  Granted, the follow up was very helpful.

Comment: This question was an example, I was referring to other questions you asked in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use AJAX, will you be writing to a MySQL DB?

Comment: We actually write to a text file, but we could write to a MySQL DB if the solution requires it.

Comment: Thanks George.  Let's say we write to a MySQL DB, do you have any thoughts about our problem? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, of course the solution is there - use AJAX.  So, I believe this is unfamiliar territory for us and would really appreciate any help you can give us to guide us towards a working solution.  Many thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FFSpw/ - This is a very simple AJAX get function. The function creates an XMLHTTP request (sends a request to the server, via HTTP, in the background) to a specific file. This file takes the variables you may have given (in this case the only variable is q=STR) and may use them in the script. Then, whatever the PHP script echos is returned to your page as 'xmlhttp.responseText' .. As I said this is a very simple AJAX function but it should give you a general idea of how it works. If you needed info about MySQL PHP scripting just let me know.

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you.  I will get my colleague to look at the script and see if he can modify it tomorrow. Thanks again!